# In Bing Maps v8 can I get a pushpin object from a layer in a loop?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

In Bing Maps v7 I was able to add pushpins to an `entityCollection` and then loop through that collection later in the code to set options or whatever.  Now, I am having trouble getting pins from the v8 layers.

Here is what I used to do in v7 after I had already added the pin to the entityCollection:

```
for (var i = 0; i < entityCollection.getLength() ; i++) {
    var pin = entityCollection.get(i);
    pin.setOptions({ visible: true });
}
```

I have changed the object `entityCollection` to a layer for v8 and I am also looping through the layer while `i < entityCollection.data.length`

Now, in Bing Maps v8, I'm having trouble getting the pin object from the layer that I have already added it to.  The code above throws an error on the setOptions line and I have also tried getting the pin with:

```
entityCollection.data[i]
```

instead of

```
entityCollection.get(i)
```

But that doesn't work either.  I'm afraid my question is too generic, because I can't find anything that actually answers my question.  I have a work around, but that causes failures later when I want to hide all the pins with certain attributes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Bing Maps v8 has done away with the `entityCollection` - though they say it's still sort of supported, you obviously don't want to be using deprecated things any more.

Anywhere you have an `entityCollection`, replace it with a `Layer` (`Microsoft.Maps.Layer`). `Layer`s expose the `getPrimitives()` method which will provide you with an array of the contents.

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(..., ...);

var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
// Add layer data...
layer.add(new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(...));

// Add layer to map
map.layers.insert(layer);

// Then you can iterate
var layerItems = layer.getPrimitives();
var len = layerItems.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var pin = layerItems[i];
    // Do something with your pin
    pin.setOptions({visible: false});
}
```

Note that if you're doing mass updates to the entire contents of the layer, such as showing or hiding every pin in the layer, you can do that directly on the layer. This will save you (the browser) a chunk of work setting each pin individually.

```
layer.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @PatrickHund You're right, a lazy answer. I'll expand now that I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in V8 layers have a getPrimitives function which returns an array containing all the shapes. You can then loop through these shapes like you would any other array.

Comment: I am having trouble here, still.  I can see that I have 16 items in my data, but when I use the "getPrimitives" function on the layer, it tells me that it is a 0 length array.

Comment: Just ran some tests on the main release branch and this is working fine. Can you provide your v8 code for creating the layer, adding data to it and then trying to  loop through it.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your help, but I just got the workaround working.  I've already spent FAR too much time on this so I'm going to go with it.  Thank you!

Comment: I am curious, though, would the individual pins having visible set to false initially cause them to not show up in the "getPrimitives" array?

Comment: If they have visibility set to false, I believe they were not returned by the function. This was changed though in the last update to the main release branch last week and now returns all shapes regardless of visibility.